# Is 3D Tic-Tac-Toe better or worse?

Tags: game-theory

The aim of this question is to compare 3D T.T.T to the 2D version.

I know there's many questions related to this, but what I want to know is the following:

1)Is it more fun?

2)Is it easier?

3)Is it more fair to the second player?

4)What is the most important/best position?

If there's any other interesting factors/comparisons you're free to add that too!

Comment: I actually have a 3D tic-tac-toe game sitting across from me. I imagine the position 'center-center' is the best position as it is analogous to the 'center' position of the 2D counterpart. For me, it is more fun but only slightly. Tic-tac-toe is a 'solved' game, i.e. if I go first I'm sure I can always win or force a draw. 3D definitely takes a bit more legwork but I feel a winning strategy could be devised. You definitely have to visualise your moves a bit more now.

Comment: How can you be "more fair to the second player" than a game where, with perfect play, [the result is always a draw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy)?

Comment: Well, "four wins" is also solved but that does not mean that it does not make fun to play it. 2D Tic Tac Toe is far too easy , but 3D Tic Tac Toe is difficult to play (to even recognize the many threads) , maybe it is a matter of training. I would not be surprised if 3D Tic Tac Toe is also solved. To solve such games , incredible comutational power is invested , I remember the brute force proof that the knight cannot "write down" a magic $8\times 8$ square.

Comment: @J.G. That's exactly why it's not fair to the second player, because even if they play perfectly all they get is a draw, they should have a possibility of winning. And even in general for Tic-Tac-Toe the first player has much more of an advantage and wins way more often.

Comment: If the second player plays perfectly, the first player can't do better than a draw either.

Comment: That's true but in general the 1st player wins way more often than the second player and has a way bigger advantage. But in 3D chess the second player has more possible spots (26) after the first play rather than (8) for the 2D one, which means more places to play and more chances to score a line of 3. At least that's what I speculate.